# App and Project Name in androiod cordova

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, netbeans

i have a question in cordova or phonegap the folowing command line

```
c:\myworkspace>cordova create MyApp com.me.myself.Myapp MyApp
```

is making MyApp applicatin name. but when i want to make an application with the Persian name E.g. for instead of calender app to make "تقویم" apps it becomes impossible in the command line therefore is ther any way to do this for example with the eclipse or netbeans IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the config.xml file, you should see a name tag in there, change it to:

```
<name>تقویم</name>
```

You'll need to edit index.html too to change the default "HelloWorld" to that as well.

Comment: it was work but after emulating which making .apk file the characters become ?????